# PowerShell Workbooks.Open with delimiter semicolon

Tags: excel, powershell, delimiter

From the [Microsoft help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819(v=office.14).aspx) I can see that it's possible to define your own `delimiter` in the part `Workbooks.Open`. I'm having issues to have it accept semicolons as a delimiter.

This is part of a bigger script where my tried changes failed:

```
$tempcsv = $excel.Workbooks.Open("$input",6,";")
$tempcsv = $excel.Workbooks.Open("$input",6,4)
```

Error message:

```
Exception calling "Open" with "3" argument(s): "Open method of Workbooks class failed"
```

Thank you for your tips guys.

Comment: If this is a .csv file, why don't you use Import-CSV instead?

Comment: @DavidBrabant: Opening a CSV file in Excel and storing it in an array of `PSCustomObject`s are two very different things. For example, OP might want to create an Excel chart of the data and save it to an XLS.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments are positional so you can't just put the format argument next to the filename. You'll need to do something like the below:

`$excel.workbooks.open("$input",$null,$null,'4')`

However, as @DavidBrabant says, you'd probably be better off using `Import-Csv`

Comment: Thank you for the tip Arco444, but I'm afraid it's not working. It still represents all the lines in one column in Excel with the delimiter `;` still in there. I also tried: `$tempcsv = $excel.Workbooks.Open("$input",$null,$null,6,$null,$null,$null,$null,4)` but no luck.

Comment: Yes, that's gone. So it does accept the input. I also tried with `";"` instead of `'4'`. Still the same result.

Comment: OK, afraid I can't help you further as I can't see the rest of your script, don't have your input file (which could be the problem?) or know what you're actually trying to do. You're now at least going in the right direction since you got rid of the error.

Comment: You're right, I'm on the right track. I'll figure it out somehow. Thank you in any case for your help.