# Powershell Excel ComObject Open Custom Delimiters

Tags: excel, powershell, csv, delimiter

I am facing a problem on the Powershell Excel ComObject where I am unable to accept a delimiter other than comma `,`. Some of the external .csv files received use a different delimiter such as semicolon `;`, pipeline `|` etc.

So, is there any solution on it to make it accepting custom delimiters? I tried using `Import-Csv $fileloop -Delimiter ';'` and it works. However I wish to remain using -ComObject to proceed as my script are all written using ComObject, and I need it to parse and check for columns and rows and some extra function.

Below is the relevant code snippet of opening .csv file for further processes:

```
$path      = "C:\Users\1.csv"
$objexcel  = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$workbook  = $objexcel.Workbook.Open($path)
$worksheet = $workbook.activesheet
$colMax    = ($WorkSheet.UsedRange.Columns).count
$intcolMax = $colMax
$intRowMax = ($WorkSheet.UsedRange.Rows).count
.....
```

---

I did research on some related topics and tested, none of them were working:

> 1. [PowerShell Workbooks.Open with delimiter semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179700/powershell-workbooks-open-with-delimiter-semicolon)
> 2. https://kb.paessler.com/en/topic/2293-i-have-trouble-opening-csv-files-with-microsoft-excel-is-there-a-quick-way-to-fix-this

Testing results:
 1. The script need high portability, which means the script will pass to another users to use, so need to avoid using setting method on the region & language settings on windows.
 2. The script need process large size and large amount of .csv file, hence need to avoid using method such as `Import-Csv $fileloop -Delimiter ';'| Export-Csv $commadelimiteroutput -Delimiter ','` to rebuild a new .csv file into comma delimiter and then use the ComObject to process.

If this is lacking information or not clear, kindly let me know.

Comment: Is Excel currently opening the file with all the data in the first column?  If so, you can use it's [text to columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-texttocolumns-method-excel?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method, to define a custom delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the [**`Open`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbooks-open-method-excel) method, use [**`OpenText`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbooks-opentext-method-excel). This allows the ability to set custom delimiters but this is not required as it also allows `$true`/`$false` for some standard delimiters.

Set the argument for semicolon `;`delimiter to `$true`, and other delimiters to `$false`.

```
$objexcel.WorkBooks.OpenText(`
                $path,        # Filename
                2,            # Origin
                1,            # StartRow
                1,            # DataType
                1,            # TextQualifier
                $false,       # ConsecutiveDelimiter
                $false,       # Tab
                $true,        # Semicolon
                $false,       # Comma
                $false,       # Space
                $false,       # Other - $true/$false
                $false,       # OtherChar - specify the character if Other is $true
                @(@(3,3),@(1,2))         # FieldInfo
)
```

For `FieldInfo`, you can get the enumerations [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlcolumndatatype-enumeration-excel). I have used the same example as documentation example  specifying column 3 as and `xlMDYFormat` column 1 as `xlTextFormat`, but in PowerShell.

Comment: Tried this solution before and also tried your code to replace my current Open method which is working. Unfortunately, the code will stopped with exception: (System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException) 
 - Error Message: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
Any idea about this exception?

Comment: And I had done some research on opentext, opentext might not working well on .csv file extension directly, fyr: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27491558/finding-powershell-names-for-excel-features